# Combining Lists in Lambda/LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

If I have variable of type `IEnumerable<List<string>>` is there a LINQ statement or lambda expression I can apply to it which will combine the lists returning an `IEnumerable<string>`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

SelectMany - i.e.

```
        IEnumerable<List<string>> someList = ...;
        IEnumerable<string> all = someList.SelectMany(x => x);
```

For each item in someList, this then uses the lambda "x => x" to get an IEnumerable<T> for the inner items. In this case, each "x" is a List<T>, which is already IEnumerable<T>.

These are then returned as a contiguous block. Essentially, SelectMany is something like (simplified):

```
static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectMany<TSource, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TResult>> selector) {

    foreach(TSource item in source) {
      foreach(TResult result in selector(item)) {
        yield return result;
      }
    }
}
```

Although that is simplified somewhat.

Answer (score 7):

How about

```
myStrings.SelectMany(x => x)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly a single method call, but you should be able to write

```
var concatenated = from list in lists from item in list select item;
```

Where 'lists' is your `IEnumerable<List<string>>` and concatenated is of type `IEnumerable<string>`.

(Technically this *is* a single method call to `SelectMany` - it just doesn't look like it was all I meant by the opening statement. Just wanted to clear that up in case anyone got confused or commented - I realised after I'd posted how it could have read).

Answer (score 0):

Make a simple method. No need for LINQ:

```
IEnumerable<string> GetStrings(IEnumerable<List<string>> lists)
{
   foreach (List<string> list in lists)
   foreach (string item in list)
   {
     yield return item;
   }
 }
```

Comment: And no reason not to use it if you are using .NET 3.5 (which we can assume from the OP), or C# 3.0 with .NET 2.0 and LinqBridge.

Comment: @Marc: You're right, especially if there's an easy "linqish" way. Sometimes people just try hard to do something the LINQ way and make simple things harder to grasp.

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ expression...

```
IEnumerable<string> myList = from a in (from b in myBigList
                                        select b)
                             select a;
```

... works just fine. :-)

`b` will be an `IEnumerable<string>` and `a` will be a `string`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another LINQ query comprehension.

```
IEnumerable<string> myStrings =
  from a in mySource
  from b in a
  select b;
```